# netbeans 7.2.1 and in 7.3beta 2 html auto complete and php go to declaration stopped working

Tags: php, html, netbeans, autocomplete

here is the problem, i have situation 1

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<di <-- here ctrl+space
</body>
</html>
```

Situation 2

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <div>
some data
</    <-- here ctrl+space
    </body>
    </html>
```

in both those auto complete it doesn't work.
Next on php when i ctrl+click (go to declaration), the IDE opens the file where the function is declared, but doesn't scroll to the actual declaration.
Both of those were working 100%, this is on ubuntu 12.4.1 + openjdk-7. I have searched for a solution, deleted the settings and cache no change, re installed, with deleted , with old,(cache and settings) no change. any other solutions to try?i really like netbeans i would hate to switch to smt else.

Comment: This should be issued directly to the Netbeans developers. In Netbeans, click on top menu item "Help" and choose entry "Report issue". Also consider You are using **beta** version... They did some changes in code completion but I doubt they would broke it totaly. I am using Netbeans (for 6 years) too and consider it as the best IDE (tried so many others...).

Comment: i consider it also :) the ide that suits me best, but the auto complete is not working on 7.2.1 and on beta i installed it just to test if the auto complete works there. Yeah, contacting some dev, maybe is the best thing to do.

Comment: I am using 7.2.1 too and have no code completion issues... Actually, it is working quite well.

Comment: How big is Your memory dump? Netbeans need to be "restarted" from time to time as it gets laggy after some time... Should be fine until memory dump is less than 400 MB, idealy less then 350 MB (this has nothing to do with Your RAM size, I have 8 GB so even if it used 1 GB it shouldn't be problem, but it is when it gets over 400 MB).

Comment: @shadyyx as i said, i didn't have any issues, until some days ago. everything was working very well on a 100%, but now...

Comment: @shadyyx with memory dump you mean, how much RAM is the program using while is running?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20567/discussion-between-shadyyx-and-nikola)

Comment: the php auto-complete and situation 1 are fixed, deleting cache, and settings folders, and re-installing, but situation 2 problem, persists.